# Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string to string storage pointer requested

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to add a candidate thorough a construct.

```
contract Election{
    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;

    uint public candidatesCount;

    constructor () public {
        addCandidate('Candidate 1');
        addCandidate('Candidate 2');
    }

    function addCandidate(string storage _name) private {

        candidatesCount ++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount,_name,0);
    }


}
```

Expected to add Candidate 1 and 2.
but facing this error:
Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "Candidate 1" to string storage pointer requested.
        addCandidate('Candidate 1');
                     ^-----------^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `storage` in your `addCandidate` function header, whereas these are `memory` variable. Do change to `memory` and you will good to go.

```
function addCandidate(string memory _name) private
```

For more insights about storage and memory keywords, have a look [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a). Hope it will save your problem.

Comment: The requester looks like he was following this tutorial https://techgeek628.medium.com/ethereum-solidity-language-syntax-in-sublime-7305e11e0fa9, and I got caught at the same point. One thing to note is that you need to use memory variable here because you are calling `addCandidate` and passing a string. This is a argument passed in through memory not stored in the blockchain. There is a more in-depth explanation here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42715/struct-array-uninitialised-storage-pointer/64851#64851?newreg=0677214a6f724ea9aa23c61b79319a38